# parametrized tests with Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js

How can I create parametrized tests with Mocha?

Sample use case: I have 10 classes, that are 10 different implementations of the same interface. I want to run the exact same suit of tests for each class. I can create a function, that takes the class as a parameter and runs all tests with that class, but then I will have all tests in a single function - I won't be able to separate them nicely to different "describe" clauses...

Is there a natural way to do this in Mocha?

Comment: here is a good example without using async http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166770/mocha-js-how-to-reuse-assertions-within-a-spec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each). It should enable you to call the same describe, it, and expect/should statements, and you can pass in the parameters to the closure.

```
var async = require('async')
var expect = require('expect.js')

async.each([1,2,3], function(itemNumber, callback) {
  describe('Test # ' + itemNumber, function () {
    it("should be a number", function (done) {
      expect(itemNumber).to.be.a('number')
      expect(itemNumber).to.be(itemNumber)
      done()
    });
  });
callback()
});
```

gives me:

```
$ mocha test.js -R spec
  Test # 1
    ✓ should be a number 
  Test # 2
    ✓ should be a number 
  Test # 3
    ✓ should be a number 
  3 tests complete (19 ms)
```

Here's a more complex example combining async.series and async.parallel: [Node.js Mocha async test doesn't return from callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151467/node-js-mocha-async-test-doesnt-return-from-callbacks/17158548#17158548)

Comment: is it really necessary to use async, would not array.every (foreach loop) do the same without the need of another third party tool ?

Comment: `async` is a great lib, my fav in Node.js-land, but wrapping Mocha describe blocks with asynchronous calls is incorrect usage of Mocha. First of all, callbacks in the async library should always be called in the next tick of the event loop, always. Second, Mocha registers all the blocks and hooks synchronously - if you register a block asynchronously, there is no guarantee that it will run. See the delay functionality in Mocha: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/362

Answer (score 47):

You do not need `async` package. You can use forEach loop directly:

```js
[1,2,3].forEach(function (itemNumber) {
    describe("Test # " + itemNumber, function () {
        it("should be a number", function (done) {
            expect(itemNumber).to.be.a('number')
            expect(itemNumber).to.be(itemNumber) 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: With `[1,4].forEach(function (itemNumber) {` I got `TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: Should I always use `array` instead of `dictionary`?

Comment: @hellboy, might want to make sure terminate previous statement with semicolon

Answer (score 12):

I know this was posted a while ago but there is now a node module that makes this really easy!! [mocha param](http://github.com/mikejsdev/mocha-param.git)

```
const itParam = require('mocha-param').itParam;
const myData = [{ name: 'rob', age: 23 }, { name: 'sally', age: 29 }];

describe('test with array of data', () => {
    itParam("test each person object in the array", myData, (person) =>   {
    expect(person.age).to.be.greaterThan(20);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually the mocha documentation specifies how to create what you want [here](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests)

```
describe('add()', function() {
  var tests = [
    {args: [1, 2], expected: 3},
    {args: [1, 2, 3], expected: 6},
    {args: [1, 2, 3, 4], expected: 10}
  ];

  tests.forEach(function(test) {
    it('correctly adds ' + test.args.length + ' args', function() {
      var res = add.apply(null, test.args);
      assert.equal(res, test.expected);
    });
  });
 });
```

The answer provided Jacob is correct just you need to define the variable first before iterating it.

Comment: do you see any drawbacks to this method vs the `mocha-param` package?  This method involves less dependencies which generally good.

Comment: I don't really see any drawbacks, as I don't believe that `mocha-param` is clearer in code, then a `foreEach` loop.

At first, I used `mocha-param`, but left it, to have less dependencies (just like you mentioned)