# Is async.series the same as event driven code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I am using node js, for my application. And have for example code like this:

```
userProvider.uploadImage(formData.imageSmall, 'full', function(err) {
         if (err) throw err;
         userProvider.uploadImage(formData.image, 'small', function (err) {
                  if (err) callback(err);
                  res.send("images loaded");
         });
});
```

is this the same as:

```
async.series([
        function(callback) {
                   userProvider.uploadImage(formData.image, 'full', function (err) {
                           if (err) callback(err);
                               callback();
                    });
        },
        function(callback) {
                   userProvider.uploadImage(formData.imageSmall, 'small', function(err){
                           if (err) callback(err);
                               callback();
                   });
        }
],
        function(err) {
                   if (err) throw err;
                   res.send("images loaded");
        }
);
```

**Are this two version of code doing the same thing? Can I consider the second version as non-blocking?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they should work identically. Yes, it's non-blocking. If you add a console.log below both of your current code blocks, it will execute before the uploadImage competes. Async.series is just a way of avoiding overly confusing callbacks.

Comment: Can you provide the link of example how to mix parallel and series tasks? (it is not about this question)

Comment: Here's an example of mixing series and parallel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151467/node-js-mocha-async-test-doesnt-return-from-callbacks/